# AVPlayerItem from URL not playing

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayeritem

I'm trying to play mp3 from Data file I downloaded with Alamofire. The song is fine, I can play it with AVAudioPlayer(data: Data). How should I play the same Data file with AVPlayer? I could not find how to create PlayerItem from Data or AVAsset from Data. 
Also, I've the url for the song path, but that URL does not work with AVPlayer somehow. Music is just not playing.

```
func startSong(withIndex: Int) {
    if let item = getItem(atIndex: withIndex) {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                print("AVAudioSession is Active")
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            let playerItem = item
            self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

func getItem(atIndex: Int) -> AVPlayerItem? {

    var item: AVPlayerItem

    var url: URL

    let song = playlist.getSong(index: atIndex)

    if PlaylistsService.sharedService.isFileDownloaded(inPath: SongPath.Offline(id: (song?.getID())!).path()) {
        url = URL(fileURLWithPath: SongPath.Offline(id: (song?.getID())!).path())
    } else if PlaylistsService.sharedService.isFileDownloaded(inPath: SongPath.Temp(id: (song?.getID())!).path()) {
        url = URL(fileURLWithPath: SongPath.Temp(id: (song?.getID())!).path())
    } else {
        self.downloadSong(song: song!)
        url = URL(fileURLWithPath: SongPath.Temp(id: (song?.getID())!).path())
    }

    item = AVPlayerItem(url: url)

    return item
}

@IBAction func playPause(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    if sender.isSelected {
        print("Play")
        self.player.play()
    } else {
        print("Pause")
        self.player.pause()
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `self.player.play()`. Does that line actually execute?

Comment: Yes it does. http://prntscr.com/d4njv4

Comment: Okay, at the point where you say `self.player.play()`, you could try logging some further info about the state of the player. What is its `currentTime`? What is its `currentItem`? If it has an item, what is that item's `status`? What is that item's `asset`?

Comment: It prints kinda correct info: http://prntscr.com/d4nnmm

Comment: Where you're logging the `status`, log instead the `status.rawValue`. That will give us a value in the console that we can actually read. We really would like to know if there's a `status` issue with this thing.

Comment: Just found out. The problem is, AVPlayerItem cannot create item from URL that points to Data file. I've added .mp3 to song path for downloading and playing, so now everything is working. Such a time waste

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found out that AVPlayerItem cannot create object from URL that points to Data file. You need to have URL with file extension ".mp3" for instance. Everything is working now when I've added the extension to path for downloading and playback.

Comment: Yeah, I should have known that when I saw the numeric name of this file. Sorry I failed to catch that.

Comment: Had the same issue; adding file extension fixed it. 

Strangely enough it seemed to have worked before today without the file extension.. I have no explanation for that one.